# Grails Web Flow - flow scope and variables management

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

Quoting a book I am currently reading:

> flow stores objects for the scope of the flow, removing them when the flow reaches an
>   end state

I would like to know if the objects are removed just *before* launching the end state or *after* executing/returning from the state ?

Secondly, do the information from GSP `<g:form>s`  get automatically stored in the `flow` map? If so, can I reference those values in the GSP to set the existing values to the appropriate `<input>s`?

All this leads to one final question - can I collect user input at many stages (views) and process them  only in one, final stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Not sure, shouldn't be hard to test :)

2: According to documentation:

> [Grails] Merges objects from the flow and conversation scopes into the
>   view model before rendering (so you shouldn't include a scope prefix
>   when referencing these objects within a view, e.g. GSP pages).

3: Yes, you can collect user input at many stages and save it in one state

Comment: AFAIK, the data I enter in a HTML form gets put in `params` map, not `flow`. So unless I process it right away - it gets lots. Correct me if I'm wrong.